# Advice on how to organize web folders to prevent paths from being found out

Tags: web, directory-traversal

In a private area of a website, I need to create a folder tree containing documents belonging to different clients.

The contents of these directories can only be accessed if you are logged in, but I want to avoid that a client can deduce the path where the documents of another client are stored.

My idea is that each client has a directory with its client number followed by a random number like this

- ../client01_43756235457634/my-documents/
- ../client02_67467459674978/my-documents/

Is this security measure enough or recommendable?

Any other ideas or advice I should consider?

My technical capabilities regarding issues such as giving exclusive permissions to certain directories to one user or another are limited, so I would need some easy-to-apply suggestions if any.

Comment: You need to design your website so that you are not accessing file locations directly using the webserver directory paths. All content should be served by the server instead of treating the webserver like a file server.

Comment: store the files outside of the web root.  (Your server-side code can serve them up, but the user can't navigate directly to them via URL.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll inform the web developer about it. About document protection and how to serve them to the logged in user, is there any quality resource I can consult on the internet?

Answer (score 3):

Your application should send the files to the client, not the webserver. If the files are directly accessed, it will be possible to any client to share the URL of any of its files and anyone can access those directly.

You application should enforce authentication, authorization and file access. If the user is valid and the user is allowed to access the file, the application should read the file from the filesystem and relay it to the client. In this case, even if the client shares the URL with another user, the second user will not be authenticated and will not be able to download the file.

Comment: Thank you ThoriumBR!

As I understand from your answer, the files should not be hosted in the public_html folder but outside of it, and from there, I should have my application serve them individually to users depending on their permissions. Is this correct?

Unfortunately in the current website I am developing I will not be able to implement this solution due to time and budget constraints, but as I will encounter a similar situation in the future, I am very interested in how to approach it.

What kind of Google search could I do to find more information and help on this topic?

Comment: It's not difficult nor time consuming. In PHP, instead of sending something like `header("Location: /data/client_1/doc_abc.txt")` you could use `readfile("data/client_1/doc_abc.txt")`.

Comment: Thanks again!
But then, should I host the documents outside the public_html directory or not?
This is to be used in a WordPress that I am not the developer of. But I will point your answer to the programmer to see if it can be easily implemented.

Comment: Nevermind, I see @pcalkins has answered this in the previous comment.